# Black Dotted line?

Tags: 3d-view, geometry, 3d-cursor, origin

New to Blender what is this black dotted line indicating?. No other objects have it when i select them. I tried setting origin to 3d cursor but th eline is still there?. [image]

Comment: Where is it coming from?

Comment: The 3d cursor . But i do have the switch parented to the base & I guess the line is indicating the the object is parented to something, but why it is leading to the cursor is beyond me.

Answer (score 5):

The black dotted lines indicate that the object (child) is parented to another object (parent). To remove parent, select child object with <kbd>LMB</kbd> and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select *Clear Parent* or *Clear and Keep Transformation*. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent an object.

What it does is that it connects one mesh to another mesh so that when you move the parent mesh the child mesh moves or scales or rotates along with it.

You can also parent an *Empty* to the mesh.

They are commonly known as relationship lines which shows relation between objects
You can turn it off in the overlays tab

[image]

Comment: Good answer, maybe you could add a note where you can turn the relationship lines off.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have edited my answer

Comment: I do have the switch parented to the base, but why it is leading to the cursor is beyond me lol

Comment: First clear parent and try parenting again.I have said it in the answer...