# what are the black dotted lines here?

Tags: object-mode, lines

[image]

I am facing a problem here i just want to fix teeths positions a bit but i noticed that with few teeths few more teeths starting to move, also those teeths are connected with each other by black dotted lines. I want them to be separated .

Comment: They must be parented to another object, to unparent press Alt P> Clear and Keep Transformations

Comment: that helped a lot thanks moonboots i have one more question if possible pls help brother . i will post it soon .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/what-are-these-black-dotted-lines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/removing-dotted-assist-lines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187133/black-dotted-line/187135#187135

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

They are parented to another object, to unparent them, select them all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformations* (so that they keep their current location, rotation and scale).